# A generic trait in Java

Tags: java, generics

In my project I have multiple strictly ordered types and I need them all to support a range operation - given two boundary values, return the list of all intermediary values.

To not repeat myself, I though I would create a "trait" like the following, which would declare the corresponding primitive operations and build a range method on top.

```
public interface Navigable {

    public Navigable previous() throws UnsupportedOperationException;

    public boolean isFirst();

    public Navigable next() throws UnsupportedOperationException;

    public boolean isLast();

    public boolean precedes(Navigable other);

    public default List<Navigable> range(Navigable to) {

        Navigable from = this;

        boolean invert = to.precedes(from);
        if (invert) {
            Navigable tmp = from;
            from = to;
            to = tmp;
        }

        List<Navigable> result = new LinkedList<>();

        while (from.precedes(to)) {
            result.add(from);
            from = from.next();
        }

        result.add(to);

        if (invert) {
            reverse(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

However, with such an interface, I need to implement the operations like this:

```
public class Item implements Navigable {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean precedes(Navigable other) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Which is, of course, incorrect. What I need is the following.

```
public class Item implements Navigable {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean precedes(Item other) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Hopefully what I'm trying to achieve is clear. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Minor typo, `preceeds` = `precedes`, if you mean "something that comes before another thing".

Comment: Given the fact you already have ordered lists, I would try to make use of Comparable and a generic method to extract the range, instead of implementing this large custom interface.

Comment: In Comparable I only have the precedes method. To implement the range method, I need the other four as well. Could you please elaborate on what you mean as an answer? That would be great. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to make your interface generic and change a bit the `abstract` methods.

For example:

```
public interface Navigable<T extends Navigable> {
    ...
    public boolean preceeds(T other);
    ..
}
```

Then, when you implement the interface, you will be able to do (without any compilation errors):

```
public class Item implements Navigable<Item> {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean preceeds(Item other) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works, but requires explicit type conversions in the range method when assigning to from, such as T from = (T) this;. Isn't there a 100% type safe solution?

Comment: @DušanRychnovský not in Java.

Comment: @DušanRychnovský - Did you try `T from = this;` instead of `Navigable from = this;`?